# different values for NSNumber long in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, long-integer, nsnumber

I have a variable which is a NSNumber of type long. It should hold the value -1.
When I log it to the Console it shows the expected value -1.

```
NSLog(@"myVariable %@", self.myVariable);
```

But the following expression in the if-clause is false.

```
    if (myVariable == [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]) {
    ...
    }
```

The debugger shows the value 72057594037927935. Does anybody know what's wrong with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare `NSNumber` to other objects, you have two options that do different things:

- You can use `==` to check if two objects represent the same exact object *instance*, or
- You can use `isEqual:` method to check if two objects represent the same *value*.

In your case the safest approach would be to use the second alternative

```
if ([myVariable isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithLong:-1]]) {
    ...
}
```

The `==` approach may or may not work, depending on the way in which you produced `myVariable`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My code works now. What a stupid failure...
But do you know why the debugger shows another value than -1?

Comment: @Nerdine123 Debugger does not know what type is inside `NSNumber`, which is capable of holding different types. So the debugger takes a guess (I think it guesses `unsigned long long`) and makes a wrong re-interpretation of the value.

Answer (score 1):

NSObject has a method: (NSString *)description
This method will define which is printed out when you put object on NSLog method.

- NSNumber inherits NSObject and description method is implemented in the way that primitive value will be printed out, and that's why you saw expected value using `NSLog(@"myVariable %@", self.myVariable);`
- Operator "==" will compare 2 objects in this case (compare both pointer and value) ==> it will return false in your case
- If you want to compare primitive value of 2 NSNumbers, use following method instead `(BOOL)isEqualToNumber:(NSNumber *)number;`